# Get the string between two characters at particular location in java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I need to extract a number between two underscores.
This has to be dynamic.
That means , I need the string between 4th and 5th underscore from the left.
Ex:  gcw_distributor_ams_200_20180419_13_10_57.enrich
The string I need is 200

Thank You

Comment: If the number always is between the 4th and the 5th, you could try to split it by _, and pick out the [3] element from the resulting list.

Comment: Um, `200` is between the **3rd and 4th** underscores (not the 4th and 5th), if I'm reading correctly.  A minor detail though; the extraction process will be essentially the same either way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split method:

```
String fileName = "gcw_distributor_ams_200_20180419_13_10_57.enrich";
String[] splittedFileName = fileName.split("_");

String requiredText = splittedFileName[3];
```